# pandas merge dataframes with same columns and reference its id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem with python pandas. I have serveral different dataframes which I want to split up into an SQLite Database. My first Dataframe `to_country`:

[image: Dataframe 1]

````
to_country = df[['country']]
to_country = to_country.rename(columns={'country': 'Name'})
to_country = to_country.drop_duplicates()
#Add Index to Country Dataframe
to_country.insert(0, 'Id', range(1, 1 + len(to_country)))
to_country=to_country.reindex(columns=['Id','Name'])
to_country = to_country.set_index('Id')
to_country.to_sql('Country', con=con, if_exists='append', index=True)```
````

This part works fine.
Now i have another Dataframe `to_state` which looks like that:

[image: Dataframe 2]

```
to_state = df[['state','country']]
to_state = to_state.rename(columns={'state': 'Name'})
to_state = to_state.drop_duplicates()
to_state.insert(0, 'Id', range(1, 1 + len(to_state)))
to_state=to_state.reindex(columns=['Id','Name','country'])
to_state = to_state.set_index('Id')
```

Now I want to replace the Country *USA* with the Id from the previous Dataframe, **i want it to look like that**:

Note the CountryId should be the attribute Id from the dataframe to_country
Id___Name___CountryId

1_____CA_________1

I tried following Statement but which only resulted in:

```
to_state = pd.merge(to_state, to_country, left_on='country', right_on="Name")
```

[image: Result]

I really do not know how should i solve this. what is even more irritating, I don't know why the Colums Id from both Dataframes disappear.

Comment: what is the expected output? have you checked the `suffixes` parameter or `merge`?

Comment: Yeah i've checked it but i am really new to pandas and i am not sure how to proceed. i mentioned the expected output in the question

Comment: please provide your two inputs as DataFrame constructors, and the explicit expected output (also as DataFrame, what is CountryID?)

Comment: try use ```join``` --> ```to_state  = to_state.join(to_country.set_index('country'), on='country')```

Comment: @mozway the CountryId should be the attribute Id from the dataframe to_country

Comment: @RafaelMRdeRezende This answers my question of the missing Id from the to_state df but the Id from the to_country df is still missing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it like that in the end:

```
#Add Countries to Database
to_country = df[['country']]
to_country = to_country.rename(columns={'country': 'Name'})
to_country = to_country.drop_duplicates()
#Add Index to Country Dataframe
to_country = to_country.reset_index()
to_country = to_country.rename(columns={"index":"ID"})
to_country['ID'] = to_country.index + 1
to_country.set_index('ID').to_sql('Country', con=con, if_exists='append', index=True)


#Add States to Database
to_state = df[['state','country']]
to_state = to_state.drop_duplicates()
#Add Index to Country Dataframe
to_state = to_state.reset_index()
to_state = to_state.rename(columns={"index":"ID", 'state': 'Name'})
to_state['ID'] = to_state.index + 1
to_state = to_state.merge(to_country, how='left', left_on='country', right_on='Name').drop(['country', 'Name_y'], axis= 1)
print(to_state)
to_state = to_state.rename(columns={'ID_x': 'ID', 'Name_x': 'Name', 'ID_y': 'Country_ID'})
print(to_state)
to_state.set_index('ID').to_sql('State', con=con, if_exists='append', index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I don't have your example dataframe, test this

```
import pandas as pd

to_country = pd.DataFrame({"id": [20,30],
                           "country": ['USA','CHINA']})
to_state = pd.DataFrame({"id": [90,80],
                           "state": ['CA','AB'],
                         "country": ['USA','CHINA']})
print(f'__________ORIGINALS DATAFRAMES__________ \n##STATE##\n{to_state}\n\n###COUNTRY###\n{to_country}')

def func(line):
    t = 0
    for x in range(0, len(to_country['country'])):
        t = to_country.loc[to_state['country'] == line['country']]
    t = t.values.tolist()
    return t[0][0]

print(f'\n_________FINAL DATAFRAME__________\n')
to_state['ID_NEW_country'] = to_state.apply(func, axis = 1)

print(f' \n{to_state}')
```

Comment: @Lars try this solution

Comment: the output of the new column is now ```Int64Index([], dtype='int64', name='Id')```

Comment: Try run this code

Comment: I created a test code, as I don't know what your dataframe looks like, you'll need to adapt it

Comment: I see but it is important that the Id of the left df is not the same as on the right one. the Matching column is the column "Country"

Comment: Only later did I realize that in the dataframe to state there is already the related country =), test the code again